# Do you need to host an application to redirect a domain?

Tags: dns, hosting, http-status-code-301

I have a domain, site.com and I want to forward it to anothersite.com

I have the DNS (namecheap) configured to point (301) site.com to anothersite.com - it works smashingly while the site.com's application server is up and running (rootBSD) - however - when I power down the server which is hosting site.com the redirect no longer works. I'm confused because the name servers are namecheap's name servers and not rootbsd, shouldn't the redirect work regardless of whether the application is hosted or not?

Must I pay for hosting and application to simply redirect a domain to another domain? and if not, how does one go about redirecting a domain to another domain without hosting the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using domain registrar's (namecheap) DNS services for "site.com", you don't have host it. We have number of customers who are parking the domain by just redirecting it to some other domain using registrar's DNS services.

Comment: I've attempted this and it seems like it would be rational, but "site.com" is still dependent upon the hosting server and I'm unable to debug as to why

Comment: Most probably, you are using namecheap nameservers but A record is still pointing server where site.com is hosted. And redirecting is taking place via web server where site.com is hosted, not via Namecheap.

Comment: There is an A record on the server where "site.com" is hosted, if I remove this A record and shutdown the server, should then "site.com" resolve to "anothersite.com"?

Comment: First make sure that, there's no A record pointing to web server in DNS at Namecheap. If it is there, set it to default. Probably, Namecheap support would do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you insist on returning 301 (Moved permanently) to clients that request site.com, there has to be a application/web server that will sent that response.
2. You can have site.com DNS name resolved to same IP address (and therefore pointed to same application/web server) as anothersite.com (usually achieved with CNAME record). That web server CAN be configured to respond (server content) to both Host names.
3. You can also configure that same web server to respond to site.com requests with 301, and redirect clients to itself, but this time with new Host: header in requests (anothersite.com)

Some DNS providers will offer 301 redirects by using only DNS, but that is usually just a nice wrapper around their own web server that will send 301 response.